# Mat-table columns collapsing on each other

Tags: html, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I have a mat-table to show the correlation between a price and a duration, where the fields can be edited. The current HTML goes like this:

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="item.durations_array">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="duration">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Duration </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; index as i">
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
          <input
            matInput
            placeholder="Duration"
            disabled="{{ !isEditing }}"
            [value]="item.durations_array[i]"
            [(ngModel)]="item.durations_array[i]"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Price </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; index as i">
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
          <input
            matInput
            placeholder="Price"
            disabled="{{ !isEditing }}"
            [value]="item.prices_array[i]"
            [(ngModel)]="item.prices_array[i]"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['duration', 'price']"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; index as i; columns: ['duration', 'price']"></tr>
  </table>
```

The problem is that the columns stack on each other like this, when I would like them side by side:

[image: Stacking columns]

I tried to include `display: block` to the table and cells but it showed no effect. I could get some results in the inspector by disabling flexbox on the table, but I thought the `display:block` would do the same?

Comment: Can you pls try "display:block" instead of "style:block"?

Comment: Sorry, had a typo there. I used display:block but wrote the wrong thing here. Corrected in original post

Comment: why not use `<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>` and `<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">`? (your'e using directly `<mat-header-cell>` and `<mat-cell>`)

Comment: This was the problem! Wonder where I had gotten the idea to forget the `th` and `td` from the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by comment of Eliseo, I had forgotten the header and cell definitions. Here's the working code:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="item.durations_array">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="duration">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Duration</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; index as i">
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
          <input
            matInput
            placeholder="Duration"
            disabled="{{ !isEditing }}"
            [value]="item.durations_array[i]"
            [(ngModel)]="item.durations_array[i]"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Price</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; index as i">
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
          <input
            matInput
            placeholder="Price"
            disabled="{{ !isEditing }}"
            [value]="item.prices_array[i]"
            [(ngModel)]="item.prices_array[i]"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['duration', 'price']"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; index as i; columns: ['duration', 'price']"></tr>
  </table>
```